# Why sometimes Firebug won't show list of Javascript files to set breakpoint?

Tags: firebug, javascript-debugger

For example, if I go to

> http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/dynamic_ajax_php.html

and go to Firebug, and set Scripts to `Enabled`, and `Show Chrome Source` and `Static, eval, and event script`, still no file list is shown so that I can view them and set a breakpoint.  In another project, I could.  Is there a reason why?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's AJAX-injected script implementation uses a technology which Mozilla Firefox does not support for debugging. Firebug gets no notification about the injected scripts. If you just used eval() it would work.